# Dynamic image size gallery with hover overlay using Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do a nice image hover overlay for a dynamic image gallery using Bootstrap 3:

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="overlay zoom"></span><img class="img-responsive img-home-portfolio" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/World_Wind_Globe_NASA_Timbuktu_1.jpg">
                </a>                  
            </div>                             
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="overlay zoom"></span><img class="img-responsive img-home-portfolio" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/World_Wind_Globe_NASA_Timbuktu_1.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="overlay zoom"></span><img class="img-responsive img-home-portfolio" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/World_Wind_Globe_NASA_Timbuktu_1.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</div>
<!-- /.section -->
```

For the overlay hover effect, I'm using this CSS:

```
a .overlay {
opacity: 0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
z-index: 0; /* for Opera */
}

a:hover .overlay {
opacity: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
z-index: 1; /* for Opera */
}

.overlay {
display: block;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.overlay.zoom {
background-image: url(http://www.open-service.org/img/zoom.png);
}
```

My problem is that the overlay extends to the div size and not just to the size of the image.

To illustate this i have created this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5AR2H/6/

Thanks.

Comment: You can set the padding on the columns to zero.

Comment: Thanks, but without the padding, the images would come together to each other: http://jsfiddle.net/jZETH/1/

I just want to add an overlay without changing the formatting.

Comment: This what you're after then? http://jsfiddle.net/5AR2H/7/

Comment: Spot on. That's it. I added a little transition just to make it nicer: http://jsfiddle.net/5AR2H/8/ Thanks!

Comment: Oops, spoke too soon. That inline-block breaks thing in Internet Explorer. Still not working.

Comment: What is IE doing with it?

Comment: It's making the images ginormous (IE11), checkout: http://jsfiddle.net/5AR2H/8/. Still haven't found a solution.